# Complexity/ polynomial time - If a problem has $x + y - 1 \choose y-1$ possible solutions & each can be evaluated in polytime, is that in P?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, computational-complexity, np-complete

I am trying to show the complexity of a problem and each instance's size is defined by parameters $x$ and $y$. For a given instance, I know there are $x+y-1 \choose y-1$ possible solutions. Each of these possible solutions can be evaluated in time that is polynomial in $x$ and $y$. Therefore, it seems that this problem should be solvable in polynomial time. Does this suggest my problem is polynomial time solvable? Or do I need to place further restrictions on the problem size (e.g., if $y$ is linear in $x$ then, the binomial coefficient grows as an exponential and so the logic falls through.)

Comment: Polynomial time in what?

Comment: To reinforce the previous comment, 'polynomial time' is generally given with respect to a single parameter (or in relatively simple situations where the time is 'separable' we might talk about, e.g., 'polynomial in the number of vertices but exponential in the dimension'. In your specific case, you could say 'for fixed $x$ it is polynomial in $y$' (and vice versa), but yes, in the regime where $x=\Theta(y)$ it would not be polynomial (in either $x$ or $y$, since the two are equivalent then).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ok, so if I want to claim this is polynomial time, I need to clarify that this claim is for fixed x or fixed y? Thanks

Comment: Exactly so! I would particularly say something like 'is polynomial in $y$ for fixed $x$' to emphasize the parameter that's being fixed and the parameter that asymptotics are being taken with respect to.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki got it. Thanks!